# Opposite of to_python in custom Django form field?

Tags: python, django

In [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning), there is a passage about `to_python` method, responsible for deserializing value. But what is recommended way to serialize data and make it ready for passing to widget? Something like `get_db_prep_value()`, but for for fields?

Comment: What is your main problem? Show some code

Answer (score 21):

There are the methods [`value()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value) and [`prepare_value()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/forms/fields.py#L131), the latter of which is undocumented but is called at the end of `value()`. If you read [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/forms/fields.py#L131) you can search for `prepare_value` and will find that e.g. the date-related fields make use of it to make adjustments to the value if necessary.

`value()` is called by [`as_widget()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1884bf8e8e9fb3f9f44a9ec216aca96f63974268/django/forms/forms.py#L581) which at the end calls the [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.render) method on the widget and passes the value returned by `value()` (and thus `prepare_value()`) along.

The latest modifications are made in the widget's [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.render) method. **Only here happens** the transformation to the final string representation, which is why in certain use cases (when the widget requires another data type than a string, e.g. select lists which require a `list` object) it is necessary to override `render()` sepecifically.

However, if the widget deals with strings (or the modifications you wish to make can be applied to the data type that will be passed to `render()`) it will be enough to hook into `prepare_value()`.

```
from django import forms

class MyField(forms.Field):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        return '{}, I am modified!'.format(value)

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    foo = MyField(initial="Hello world")
```

Testing the snippet in the shell:

```
In [1]: MyForm().as_p()
Out[1]: '<p><label for="id_foo">Foo:</label> <input id="id_foo" name="foo" type="text" value="Hello world, I am modified!" /></p>'
```